# React Hook: rerender list item cause infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

I create a list of users (work well), and for certain users, I need to call new async function (fetch) to update data. But that causes an infinite loop.

Here my code:

```
function UserTableRow(props) {
 const [pointOfSales, updatePointOfSales] = useState([])


  function Pos({ id }) {

  useEffect(() => {
  let mounted = true

    pointOfSaleService.getById(id).then((pointOfSale: PointOfSale) => {
      if (mounted && !pointOfSales.includes(pointOfSale)) {
        updatePointOfSales([...pointOfSales, pointOfSale]) <---- loop here
      }
    })
    return function cleanup() {
      mounted = false
    }
  }, [])

  if (pos) {
    return <Typography variant="body2">{pointOfSales[pointOfSales.length-1].name}</Typography>
  } else {
    return <span />
  }
}

return (
  <TableRow>
    <UserTableCell component="th" scope="row">
      {user.name}
    </UserTableCell>
   ...
    <UserTableCell align="left">
      {user.posId > 0 && <Pos id={user.posId} />}
    </UserTableCell>
  </TableRow>
)
```

}

What I tested :

- if I put pos or pointOfSales as dependency of useEffect, I had the same result
- idem if I don' use useEffet, just pointOfSaleService.getById(id) directly

There are 2 main problems I don't understand.

- The array is well filled, but why this line **!pointOfSales.includes(pointOfSale)** does not work?
- Why pointOfSales is updated with "updatePointOfSales" althought the method pointOfSaleService.getById(id) always retrieves the same pointOfSale?

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try simplifying your code. In my opinion, `Pos` is a presentational component and it should not perform any request (that should be done in the `UserTableRow`).

```
function UserTableRow({ user }) {
 const [pointOfSales, updatePointOfSales] = useState([])

 useEffect(() => {
   let mounted = true

    pointOfSaleService.getById(user.posId).then(pointOfSale => {
      // I assume pointOfSale is a string
      // if it does, consider changing pointOfSales to string instead of Array
      if (mounted && !pointOfSales.includes(pointOfSale)) {
        updatePointOfSales([...pointOfSales, pointOfSale])
      }
    })
    return function cleanup() {
      mounted = false
    }
 }, [user.posId])

 return (
      <TableRow>
        <UserTableCell component="th" scope="row">
         {user.name}
        </UserTableCell>
        ...
        <UserTableCell align="left">
         {
           pointOfSales.length > 0 
           ? <Typography variant="body2">{pointOfSales[pointOfSales.length-1].name}</Typography> 
           : <span/> 
         }
        </UserTableCell>
     </TableRow>
 )

}
```

one last thing about the approach you have implemented is that it performs really bad. Image having 50 users, when you render their corresponding rows, you will issue 50 requests to your server (I would rather include the pointOfSale when retrieving the users).

Comment: Thanks, it seems working. I changed few things, but everything is ok now